# What is the Ideal Keyword Placement in a URL for Inner Location Pages?

Tags: url, local-seo, url-keywords

I'm working on a website with 100s of locations. There is a location search page (Find Widget Dealer), a page for each state (Tennessee Widget Dealers) and finally a page for each individual location which has localized unique content and contact info (Nashville Widget Dealer). My question is is related to **how I should structure my URL and the keywords within the URL.** Keywords in my examples being the location and the product (i.e. widget).

**Here is a quick overview of each of the 3 tiered pages, with the Nashville page being the most optimized:**

- Find Widget Dealer: Dealer Page only includes a location search bar and bullet list links to states
- Tennessee Widget Dealers: Page includes brief unique content for the the state and basic listing info for each location along with links to the local page)
- Nashville Widget Dealer: Page includes a good amount of unique content for this specific location (Most optimized page)

**That said, here are the 3 URL structure options I am considering:**

1. domain/**widget**-dealers/tennesee/nashville
2. domain/dealers/tennesee-**widget**-dealers/nashville
3. domain/dealers/tennesee/nashville-**widget**-dealer

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: The basic gist is to put the more important parts earlier i nthe URL. After  that, broader topics earlier, more specific parts later.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment before editing my question for review again. Thank you!